# To help in/on these topics - offer help in/on these topics

Tags: prepositions, collocations

I wonder which preposition goes best with help in these phrases:

... people who ** could help **:

- in these topics
- on these topics

... people who ** could *offer* help**

- in these topics
- on these topics

I was typing a thank you comment in this post: [Into and out of 'time out' for kids](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100427/into-and-out-of-time-out-for-kids), but I felt I lost my bearings on which preposition to use; and when I quickly looked up on Google I didn't find immediate results. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=help%20in%20these%20topics%2Chelp%20on%20these%20topics&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chelp%20on%20these%20topics%3B%2Cc0) was not of much help.

I might get it right if I took a break and came back later but I thought I'd ask to test my guess and for future reference anyway- I guess phrases that pull up *help/in/topic* together sound familiar; and I'd venture a guess that the pattern *offer help on these topics* is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Topics work with the preposition *on*.  If X is part of topic Y, then X can be said to be "on" Y.

> We are debating on this topic today.
>
> Today's show is on construction materials.
>
> Discussion is happening on WWII warfare tactics (topic = "WWII warfare tactics").